# How to position fixed element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-position

I have a very simple problem. I have a player on my website which and it's class looks like that:

```
.jp-type-playlist
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Also I have a popup menu which should fire on click.

```
.jp-playlists
{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

Both blocks are located on the same level:

```
<!-- Playlists -->
<div class="jp-playlists">...</div>
<!-- Player -->
<div class="jp-type-playlist">...</div>
```

I want to position it next to the player and I don't know how to do it. I tried to use .offset() but it returns only offset from the top of the document which is useless if the page is scrolled down. I tried to use jQuery UI .position(), but it worked in the same way as a previous solution.

Please help me with my problem. The link to the website: http://synthetic.fm/#&&Genre=&Artist=&Album=

Playlist menu looks like small yellow list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var $playList = $('.jp-type-playlist');
$('.jp-playlists').css({
    left: ($playList.offset().left + $playList.width()),
    top: $playList.offset().top + $(document).scrollTop()
});
```

Comment: I tried that. .offset().top returns elements position from the top of the document. So, when I scroll the document down it returns very large value. Actually I want to get an offset from the top of the window, but not from the document...

Comment: Hmm... I'm gonna try it and then I'll report. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem like that:

```
$('.jp-playlists').css('bottom', $(window).height() + $(document).scrollTop() - $('.jp-playlists-show').offset().top + $('.jp-playlists-show').height() / 2);
$('.jp-playlists').css('left', $('.jp-playlists-show').offset().left - $('.jp-playlists').width() / 2 + $('.jp-playlists-show').width() / 2);
```

ShankarSangoli, thanks!